# Issues Initializing Contract with Struct as Constructor Params

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

I am trying to initialize a new contract within a foundry test. Here is a code snippet:

```
contract ExampleTest is Test {
    using stdStorage for StdStorage;

    Queue queue;

    // ["q1", "", false, 0, 0, "0x0000000000000000", 3, "0x0000000000000000"]

    function setUp() external {
        queue  = new Queue([
            "q1",           
            "",            
            false,          
            0,             
            0,              
            "0x0000000000000000",    
            3,
            "0x0000000000000000"       
        ]);
```

Furthermore here is a code snippet from the Queue contract:

```
struct QueueAccountData {
        uint8[32] name;
        uint8[64] metadata;
        address authority;
        uint32 oracleTimeout;
        uint64 reward;
        uint64 minStake;
        bool slashingEnabled;
        BorshDecimal _varianceToleranceMultiplier;       // @dev: added below (assuming implementation is same as in Aggregator)
        uint32 _feedProbationPeriod;
        uint32 _currIdx;
        uint32 _size;
        uint32 _gc_idx;
        uint64 _consecutiveFeedFailureLimit;
        uint64 _consecutiveOracleFailureLimit;
        bool _unpermissionedFeedsEnabled;
        bool _unpermissionedVrfEnabled;
        Decimal _curatorRewardCut;
        bool _lockLeaseFunding;
        address mint;
        bool _enableBufferRelayers;
        uint8[968] _ebuf;
        uint32 _maxSize;
        address _dataBuffer;
    }

constructor(QueueAccountData memory) {

}
```

The error message is as follows:

`TypeError: Unable to deduce common type for array elements.`

Answer (score 0):

I think the

```
 [ "q1", "",  false, 0, 0, "0x0000000000000000", 3, "0x0000000000000000" ]
```

you are passing in the constructor, doesn't fit with the `QueueAccountData` struct type.